# Match a curl request to NancyFx service from browser js

Tags: javascript, curl, file-upload, nancy, asyncfileupload

I've got a microservice (in NancyFx) that works as expected for the following [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se) command:

```
curl --verbose   --form file=@"C:\test\image.png"  http://localhost:8080/file/upload
```

The file shows up inside Nancy as expected at:

```
context.Request.Files[0]  //The file bytes are here, yeah!!
```

Now I've got to get my web-client to send a selected file to the same service, in the same way.

TLDR; You can skip my failure examples below if you'd like

I've tried several versions of the following with no success:

```
    var uploadForm = new FormData();  
    // Add the file to the request.
    uploadForm.append("file", file, name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/file/upload', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200)
            alert('File ' + name + 'Upload successfully!!!');
        else errorFn("Upload Failure on file " + name);
    };

    //Send the data
    xhr.send(uploadForm);
```

and several versions of the following, also with no success:

```
    var postConfig = {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/file/upload',
        data: uploadForm,
        processData: false, //tries without this as well
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        cache: false,
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    }
    $.ajax(postConfig);
```

I've tried the above with

1. file = direct reference to $('MyFileSelectorControl').files[0]
2. file being set with the following code:

   ```
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (result) {
       var fileContent = new Uint8Array(result.target.result);
       var encContent = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray();
       for (var b = 0; b < fileContent.length; b++) {
           encContent.append(fileContent[b]);
       }
       <Set file = encContent and send AJAZ as above>
   };
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput);
   ```

   3. Setting file = to fileContent  above (IOW, after it has been through the reader, but not encoded.)

How do I submit this file from javascript (jQuery or standard) so that it works like it does from cURL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that finally worked.  (Admittedly, I had thought I had already tried this and said so in my question)

```
var file = $('MyFileSelectorControl').files[0];
var uploadForm = new FormData();  
// Add the file to the request.
uploadForm.append("file", file, name);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/file/upload', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200)
        alert('File ' + name + 'Upload successfully!!!');
    else errorFn("Upload Failure on file " + name);
};

//Send the data
xhr.send(uploadForm);
```